# Error when creating symlink. ServerID: 1.? Apache? or Perl?

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I run a file sharing script CGI its been running for 50 days no problem up till about 5 days ago it keeps giving this error in the log while people could NOT download from it. it would give a `500 Internal Server Error`

```
2014:05:24 08-47-31 Error when creating symlink. ServerID: 1. FileID:127
Server closed connection without sending any data back at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 372.
```

I messed around, Figured out I could restart Apache and it would work again but only for say 5-40 mins it was just random. Then I ran EasyApache the problem stopped for 2 days. Well now the problem is back again :/

Its not a Server Overload or anything like that. Its a pretty high powered server.

Comment: You need to ignore the fact that it's been running for a long time and diagnose the source of the error: `Error when creating symlink.`.  Your script must not be trapping all your error conditions or you would have a much better error message than that, but you need to fix the code either way.  We're obviously not going to be able to help you at all with what you've provided.

Comment: If you look at your apache access log are you getting any dodgy requests? When you have a server on the internet you'd be amazed what requests people will throw at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Around line 372 in Methods.pm it says:

```
sub read_response_headers {
    my($self, %opt) = @_;
    my $laxed = $opt{laxed};

    my($status, $eol) = my_readline($self, 'Status');
    unless (defined $status) {
        die "Server closed connection without sending any data back";
    }
```

So it looks like you are losing network connectivity.

Comment: Thing is though about that its not ... Everything else is working fine, along with the 10 other domains running on the server. Even the Script Comes UP and even have the count down they have to wait for and when they click to download there greeted with 500 Server Error.  While my other domains and PHP scripts are working along just fine.